# unable to sort a map containing date-time

Tags: clojure

I am trying to sort a map based on its date-time value. The code below uses the function from clj-time -

```
(def items {:a {:time (date-time 2013 12)} :b {:time (date-time 2013 11)}})

(sort-by #(-> % items :month) before? items)
```

> IllegalArgumentException No implementation of method: :before? of
>   protocol: #'clj-time.core/DateTimeProtocol found for class: nil 
>   clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn (core_deftype.clj:527)

However I get the above exception. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
(sort-by (fn [[k v]] (-> v :time)) before? items)
```

In case you want a sorted-map then you need to make the date-time map as the key and :a :b as values cause sorted-map sort on key value:

```
(->>  (into [] items)
      (map (fn [[k v]] [v k]))
      (flatten)
      (apply sorted-map-by #(before? (%1 :time) (%2 :time))))
```

Comment: its the first solution I want to implement, as my key is not date-time. However I still get the exception mentioned in my question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
#(-> % items :month)
```

equivalents to

```
#(let [res1 (items %)
       res2 (:month res1)]
   res2)
```

`res1` is always `nil` because you give map entries of `items` to it, so res2 is `nil` too. And `before?` throws this exception on `nil` parameters.

Try this

```
(def items {:a {:time (date-time 2013 10)}
            :c {:time (date-time 2013 12)}
            :b {:time (date-time 2013 11)}})

(sort-by (comp :time second) before? items)

=> ([:a {:time #<DateTime 2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z>}]
    [:b {:time #<DateTime 2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z>}]
    [:c {:time #<DateTime 2013-12-01T00:00:00.000Z>}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use the `before?` function. `sort-by` will take care of sorting in ascending order:

```
(def items {:a {:time (clj-time.core/date-time 2013 10)}
            :c {:time (clj-time.core/date-time 2013 11)}
            :b {:time (clj-time.core/date-time 2012 11)}})

(sort-by (comp :time second) items)

=> ([:b {:time #clj-time/date-time "2012-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"}]
    [:a {:time #clj-time/date-time "2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"}]
    [:c {:time #clj-time/date-time "2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"}])
```